# Is it possible to export/save tooltips with MSChart in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I currently have two separated servers; an internal server with a database and an external server to which clients have access. On the internal server I want to query a database and generate a number of charts based on requests made by clients. So far I can do that, generate the charts, and using the `SaveImage()` function export those charts as PNG images I can send to the client server.

However, I would like to also export the tooltips generated by MSChart, so when the clients view the charts (as pre-rendered PNGs) they can also view the tooltips. I'm under the impression that the MSChart control generates those tooltips as a `<map><area>` which is output to the page when the charts are rendered, but is it possible to have that output to, for example, a text file, so that when I call the PNG charts I can also call and output the relevant map?

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of the MSChart serializer will work, take a look here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019770/printing-of-ms-chart-in-asp-net-application) article will spark an idea for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES, it is possible, albeit indirectly, with the `Serializer()` function**

By using `Chart.Serializer.Save("filename.xml")`, you can export all of the details needed to recreate a chart as an XML file. This means you don't also have to use `SaveImage()` to export a PNG, because when you import the XML with `Chart.Serializer.Load("filename.xml")` in your client-side page, you will be able to re-render the chart, tooltips and all.

If it is absolutely necessary to produce a PNG file with an associated `<map><area>`, you may be able to export the XML (or to a a memory stream) and then process that data to reproduce the necessary HTML and save it as plain text (eg: to a database). If the client-side server has no ASP processing capabilities, this might be a necessary extra step on the server-side application.

Thanks to [Chris Zeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30213/chris-zeh) for the lead to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article that helped me figure out this solution.